# How to edit SHA256 in java

Tags: java, hash, sha256

It was hard for me to explain in the title, but I would like to create a program which takes certain text, say `hello0`, hash it in sha256, and see if it has two leading zeros. If so, print hash. If not, make it `hello1`, then `hello2` and so on until two leading zeros are found. Here is a few ways I found on how to create my sha256 hash from text:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class sha 
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{

int yeah = 40;
String password = "previousblock14currentblock" + yeah;


    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(password.getBytes());

    byte byteData[] = md.digest();

    //convert the byte to hex format method 1
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
     sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    System.out.println("Hex format : " + sb.toString());

    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
 for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
  String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
      if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
      hexString.append(hex);
 }
 System.out.println("Hex format : " + hexString.toString());

}
}
```

When you run the code you receive `Hex format : 0a0a30b1031fa60b8fa9478a070b03333df75017fd61c1b1c7e16bd929831ef5`. This has one leading zero but I want two. I don't know what to do next, but i believe I set everything up correctly. How would I go about creating a while or if statement, each time adding `yeah` by 1? Would this be the best way of doing it?

The issue is that when I create a while loop the sha256 hash wont update, so it always prints 0a0a30b1031fa60b8fa9478a070b03333df75017fd61c1b1c7e16bd92983‌​1ef5. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong and wanted to see how someone else would do it.

thank you for your help.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to create a loop, and how to increment an integer inside that loop, right? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Use this to convert to hex string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41787842/4899193

Comment: I understand how a loop works haha, the issue is that when I create a while loop the sha256 hash wont update, so it always prints `0a0a30b1031fa60b8fa9478a070b03333df75017fd61c1b1c7e16bd929831ef5`. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong and wanted to see how someone else would do it.

Comment: The ask THAT question, and post the code of your loop that doesn't work the way you expect it to work. Don't just ask how to write a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Sha {

    private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((array[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final int MAX_PASS_ATTEMPTS = 40000;

        final String PASS_PREFIX = "previousblock14currentblock";

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PASS_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
            String password = PASS_PREFIX + i;

            md.reset();
            md.update(password.getBytes());
            byte[] hash = md.digest();

            //System.out.println(byteArrayToHexString(hash));

            if (hash[0] == 0 && hash[1] == 0) {
                System.out.println("Password: " + password);
                System.out.println("Hash: " + byteArrayToHexString(hash));
                return;
            }
        }       

        System.out.println("No luck after " + MAX_PASS_ATTEMPTS + " tries.");
    }
}
```

By the way, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) is the great resource to learn about Java control flow statements.